# My var doesn't seem to want to inherit from a custom class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, undefined

I'm really sorry if this ends up being a noob question.

I have a var that is set up as a new object of my class. However, I keep getting error 1120 whenever I test it. I know that error means it's an undefined property. I tried changing the scope of it (to every possible place in the main class. Namely the class, just after the imports and the constructor).

The code is supposed to be part of a character creator for Dungeons and Dragons 4e.

Have tried for hours to find a solution but I'm just not sure. Will include my Attributes class if it's any help.

```
var Humon:Attributes = new Attributes
```

It's declared as part of my main class:

```
package
{
//imports
import com.Classes.Attributes;
import flash.text.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip()
{

    private var Humon:Attributes = new Attributes;

    public function Main()
    {
            Atties.text = (Humon.getStr()+", "+Humon.getDex()+", "+Humon.getCon()+", "+Humon.getInt()+", "+Humon.getWis()+",  "+Humon.getCha()+".");
            var res:int = Humon.getStr();
            trace("Humon Str is "+res+".");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the class Attributes.

```
//This class defines the frame work for all classes used

package
{

    public class Attributes extends Object
{

//vars go here

//saves variables  (get auto updated through function makeDefaultModsAndSaves())
    static var refSave:int = 0;
    static var forSave:int = 0;
    static var wilSave:int = 0;
//attribute modifiers (get auto updated through function makeDefaultModsAndSaves())
    static var StrMod:int = 0;
    static var DexMod:int = 0;
    static var ConMod:int = 0;
    static var IntMod:int = 0;
    static var WisMod:int = 0;
    static var ChaMod:int = 0;


//2d array to store attributes [x][y] where x is str/dex/con/int/wis/cha and y is value
        static var Attrs:Array = new Array(); 
        Atts[0] = [10]; 
        Atts[1] = [10]; 
        Atts[2] = [10]; 
        Atts[3] = [10]; 
        Atts[4] = [10]; 
        Atts[5] = [10]; 

    function Attributes()
    {
    //constructor
        trace("Attributes loaded");
    }

 //functions to GET Attributes
    function getStr():int
        {
            var Str:int = 0;
            Str = Atts[0][0];
            trace ("Getting Str. It is " + Str);
            return Str;
        }
//different functions, same syntax as getStr above
function getDex():int
    {
        var Dex:int = 0;
        Dex = Atts[1][0];
        trace ("Getting Dex. It is" + Dex);
        return Dex;
    }

function getCon():int
    {
        var Con:int = 0;
        Con = Atts[2][0];
        trace ("Getting Con. It is" + Con);
        return Con;
    }

function getInt():int
    {
        var Int:int = 0;
        Int = Atts[3][0];
        trace ("Getting Int. It is" + Int);
        return Int;
    }

function getWis():int
    {
        var Wis:int = 0;
        Wis = Atts[4][0];
        trace ("Getting Wis. It is" + Wis);
        return Wis;
    }

function getCha():int
    {
        var Cha:int = 0;
        Cha = Atts[5][0];
        trace ("Cha is" + Cha);
        return Cha;
    }

//functions to SET Attributes
function setStr(input:int)
{
    //trace old value
    trace("Old Strength is: "+Atts[0][0]+".");

    //assign new value from whatever source
    Atts[0][0] = input;

    //check new strength
    trace("New Strength is: "+Atts[0][0]+"./n");

    //and update mods/saves
    makeDefaultModsAndSaves()
}

    //different functions, same syntax as getStr above
function setDex(input:int)
{
    trace("Old Dexterity is: "+Atts[0][0]+".");
    Atts[1][0] = input;
    trace("New Dexterity is: "+Atts[0][0]+"./n");
    makeDefaultModsAndSaves()
}

function setCon(input:int)
{
    trace("Old Constitution is: "+Atts[2][0]+".");
    Atts[2][0] = input;
    trace("New Constitution is: "+Atts[2][0]+"./n");
    makeDefaultModsAndSaves()
}

function setInt(input:int)
{
    trace("Old Intelligence is: "+Atts[3][0]+".");
    Atts[3][0] = input;
    trace("New Intelligence is: "+Atts[3][0]+"./n");
    makeDefaultModsAndSaves()
}

function setWis(input:int)
{
    trace("Old Wisdom is: "+Atts[4][0]+".");
    Atts[4][0] = input;
    trace("New Wisdom is: "+Atts[4][0]+"./n");
    makeDefaultModsAndSaves()
}

function setCha(input:int)
{
    trace("Old Charisma is: "+Atts[5][0]+".");
    Atts[5][0] = input;
    trace("New Charisma is: "+Atts[5][0]+"./n");
    makeDefaultModsAndSaves()
}

//function to calculate and apply modifiers based off of ATTRIBUTES ONLY
        function makeDefaultModsAndSaves():int
        {

            for(var i:int = 0; i < Atts.length; i++)
            {
                var modifier: int = 0;
                trace("Current loop: "+i);              
                modifier = (((Atts[i][0])-10)/2);

            switch (i)
            {

           case 0:
           StrMod = modifier;
           trace("Strength is "+Atts[i] +" and has a modifier of "+StrMod+".\n");
           break;

        case 1:
        DexMod = modifier;
        trace("Dexterity is "+Atts[i]+" and has a modifier of "+DexMod+". The reflex save bonus is "+refSave+".\n");
        break;

        case 2:
        ConMod = modifier;
        forSave = modifier;
        trace("Constitution is "+ Atts[i]+" and has a modifier of "+ConMod+". The fortitude save bonus is "+forSave+".\n");
        break;

        case 3:
        IntMod = modifier;
        trace("Intelligence is " +Atts[i]+" and has a modifier of "+IntMod+".\n");
        break;

        case 4:
        WisMod = modifier;
        trace("Wisdom is "+Atts[i]+" and has a modifier of "+WisMod+". The will save bonus is "+wilSave+".\n");
        break;

        case 5:
        ChaMod = modifier;
        trace("Charisma is "+Atts[i]+" and has a modifier of "+ChaMod+".\n");
        break;
        } 


        }
    return modifier;
}

//temporary var to initialise function.
var arse:int = makeDefaultModsAndSaves()


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the parentheses:

   ```
   public class Main extends MovieClip()
   public class Main extends MovieClip
   ```
2. Ensure that Main.as and Attributes.as placed in the same folder.
   Remove unnecessary import statement:

   ```
   import com.Classes.Attributes;
   ```
3. There is an error here:

   ```
   static var Attrs:Array = new Array();
   Atts[0] = [10];
   Atts[1] = [10];
   Atts[2] = [10];
   ...
   ```

   Rename Attrs to Atts.
4. In the Main.as class you address to the Atties. What is Atties?

Comment: Atties is a text box on the stage that ought to show whatever stats are returned.

Made your changes and it seems better. No errors this time however nothing else happens either. No traces or anything.

2 - How come that import was uncessary? I thought if you wanted to have an object inherit properties that you needed access to the class its inheriting from. Or is it because the class shares the same folder, it can reference it anyway without having to have the import statement?

Comment: 1) I see all traces. 2) If two classes placed in the same folder you don't need to use import statement.

Comment: Tried it again and magically, it's all working, Thanks for the assist